# Issuing a command prompt command in Java

Tags: java, cmd

I tried this:

```
Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\spacitron\\batchfiles\\mybatch.bat");
```

But all that happens is the command prompt pops up on the screen.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: I suspect the error is with your `mybatch.bat` file. What happens when you run `mybatch.bat` in command prompt normally?

Comment: Java Devil, when I double click on mybatch.bat the command prompt comes up and executes the script.

Answer (score 1):

As to your particular problem, I would suspect the command line arguments are getting mangled.  This is actually a faily common problem with `Runtime#exec`.

Instead, I'd recommend that you use `ProcessBuilder` instead.  It's much more forgiving with the command line parameters and deals with things like spaces much better.

For exammple...

**MyBatch.bat**

@echo off

echo This is a test message

**RunBatchCommand**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class RunBatchCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "start", "/c", "MyBatch.bat");
        pb.redirectError();
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStreamConsumer isc = new InputStreamConsumer(p.getInputStream());
            new Thread(isc).start();
            int exitCode = p.waitFor();

            System.out.println("Command exited with " + exitCode);
            if (isc.getCause() == null) {
                System.out.println(isc.getOutput());
            } else {
                isc.getCause().printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class InputStreamConsumer implements Runnable {

        private InputStream is;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private IOException cause;

        public InputStreamConsumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int in = -1;
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) in);
                    System.out.print((char) in);
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                cause = exp;
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected String getOutput() {
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public IOException getCause() {
            return cause;
        }

    }
}
```

Which generates...

```
This is a test message
Command exited with 0
This is a test message
```